# How to generate PKCS8 key with PEM encode using AES-128-ECB Alg in OpenSSL

Tags: ssl, cryptography, certificate, openssl, pem

I want know How to generate below key [AES-128-ECB] using openssl cmd.

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED
DEK-Info: AES-128-ECB,379AB79E55059F9A
gaakm48Y8qYA997fJREN4JtfVkfTdnVzaZK2
......................................
gaakm48Y834748453273tfVkfTdnVzaZK2 ....
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

From our internal code using below we have cretaed abv key , now I have to generate same format key using openssl cmd
generated RSA Key  then convert to PKCS8  then done PEM_encode using AES-128-ECB Alg

Is OpenSSL cmd tool can only use DES-EDE3-CBC  alg to generate the keys ?

Comment: Personally, I would frown seriously upon anything that has known plain text (such as PKCS#8 encoding) and uses ECB encryption. I'm not saying your private key is now in the clear or whatever, but there are pretty good reasons why ECB encoding should not be used here - hence probably the lack of support from openssl.

Answer (score 2):

It is not clear how are you generating your key. Considering you are running `openssl genrsa`, you can try:

```
openssl genrsa -aes128
```

Comment: openssl genrsa -aes128  generated in CBC mode and also its not in PKCS8 format

Comment: Your example is not in PKCS8 format also. Anyway, you can get a pkcs8 aes-128-ecb-encrypted key simply by `openssl genrsa | openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -v2 aes-128-ecb`.

Comment: First I have to generated pksc8 key with out encryt.               using : "openssl genrsa 1024 | openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -nocrypt"  after that how can I encode using pem encode with aes-128-ecb DEK Alg ?

Comment: `openssl pkcs8` can produce PKCS8 ecnrypted output in one go, you don't need that extra unencrypted pkcs8 step.

Comment: But Why I am unable to get the "Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED DEK-Info: AES-128-ECB,379AB79E55059F9A " in the pksc8 encrypted kley I generated ? I need key in above format , pls help

Comment: Proc-Type: blabla is NOT a PKCS#8 format, it is PEM RSA Private key format. You can't create PEM RSA private key with aes-128-ecb cipher using openssl command-line tools. But you can do this in software using OpenSSL API.