# How to read an encrypted private key in the form of BEGIN PRIVATE KEY?

Tags: encryption, openssl, rsa, pem, passphrase

I have a private key that is in the following format, unfortunately I can't share the actual key, so the base64 code is masked:

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED
DEK-Info: AES-128-ECB,4C425124E54FEA716FEE437A01473736

****************************************************************
****************************************************************
****************************************************************
****************************************************************
****************************************************************
****************************************************************
****************************************************************
****************************************************************
****************************************************************
****************************************************************
****************************************************************
****************************************************************
****************************************************************
**********************==
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

So I have little application that comes from 2010, written by **Huawei** called **CardManufactureFileDecrypt** that uses the private key, a certificate and the password / passphrase to successfully decrypt files that contain vouchers, so from that I can deduce that the file is intact, also that the password or passphrase I have is correct.

So my question is does anyone know how to read an encrypted private key in the form of BEGIN PRIVATE KEY? Or perhaps what libraries from about 10 years ago would have produced / consumed keys in this style?

When I try to read the private key with openssl I get the following error(s):

```sh
$ openssl rsa -in PrivateKey_E8.p8 -out PrivateKey_E8_unencrypted.p8
unable to load Private Key
139978370384320:error:0906B082:PEM routines:PEM_get_EVP_CIPHER_INFO:unexpected dek iv:../crypto/pem/pem_lib.c:551:
```

Or:

```sh
$ openssl pkcs8 -in PrivateKey_E8.p8 -out PrivateKey_E8_unencrypted.p8
Error reading key
140719466078656:error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line:../crypto/pem/pem_lib.c:745:Expecting: ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY
```

Comment: When you say you've tried to decrypt this with openssl, what did you try? I'd expect `openssl rsa -in <filename> -out <filename>` would handle this format. Does it not? Alternately using `openssl pkcs8`.

Comment: Thank you @RobNapier, I have updated the question to show what errors I get from `openssl`.

Comment: Yeah; that first error kind of matches my expectation. ECB doesn't use an IV, and this is where openssl is rejecting it: https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/e7fb44e7c3f7a37ff83a6b69ba51a738e549bf5c/crypto/pem/pem_lib.c#L546-L553. You might try removing the IV (the part after the comma, and the comma itself).

Comment: Thanks @RobNapier, I think you are pointing me in the right direction, I tried what you suggested, but openssl failed with an unsupported encryption warning ([line 543](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/e7fb44e7c3f7a37ff83a6b69ba51a738e549bf5c/crypto/pem/pem_lib.c#L543)). I see that user [abbot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4001) commented on question [8500874](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8500874) _You can't create PEM RSA private key with aes-128-ecb cipher using openssl command-line tools.  But you can do this in software using OpenSSL API_